# How do I transfer my second Minecraft license to another account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I bought another copy of Minecraft to let my kids play the game on different computers, but unfortunately I bought both copies from the same Microsoft account and now I am unable to download the second copy with different account name.

Is there any way to transfer the licenses to the second computer or second user? I tried to refund the money to buy it again with different Microsoft account but there is no  refund option.

Comment: As far as I know, shouldn't be downloading a Minecraft copy from another computer free, as long as Minecraft was purchased through the account used?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you can download it for free on a different computer if you use the same account. However, you're only able to transfer accounts if you have a really old account (One when minecraft was bought on mojang.com) But you should be safe, as Minecraft accounts don't link to other accounts. (Basically unless you sign in with usernames instead of emails you should be fine)